# as.Date function not working

Tags: r

I have a huge data set I am working with. Some of the months are in the format `01/01/2010` and others are `1/1/2010`.

When I run `as.Date(Dates, format="%y/%d/%m")` all of the latter dates change the year to 2020. What is going on here?

Comment: you probably want `format="%d/%m/%y"`?

Answer (score 4):

Your format statement is not correct. Try this:

```
d1 <- "01/01/2010"
d2 <- "1/1/2010"
> as.Date(d1, format='%d/%m/%Y')
#[1] "2010-01-01"
> as.Date(d2, format='%d/%m/%Y')
#[1] "2010-01-01"
```

For dates with different formats of the year, the `lubridate` package can be used:

```
library(lubridate)
d1 <- "1/1/10"
d2 <- "01/01/2010"
parse_date_time(d1, "dmy")
#[1] "2010-01-01 UTC"
parse_date_time(d2, "dmy")
#[1] "2010-01-01 UTC"
```

Comment: I just tried that and now for the 01/01/10 dates I am getting 0010-01-01 but the 1/1/2010 dates work fine.

Comment: @Elle Then you have something that you failed to mention in your original question: dates in different formats. They will all need to be in the same format for you to do anything with them.

Comment: So I have over 400,000 rows of data, I have to go through each and every one to change them? There is no way I can do this on R?

Comment: If you only have the last decade, like in `1/1/10` , the suitable format would be `%d/%m/%y`  with a lower case y in `%y`, whereas the format of dates including the centuries requires a capital Y, as posted above. Hope this helps.

Comment: So is there any way I can filter out each of those types of formats and apply the as.Date function to each one?

Comment: You can select only those in a specific format using `grepl` and regex. You'll want to work with a copy of the column, though, to avoid format collisions. You'll also need to do an inventory of your data and determine just how badly it's been entered, i.e. how many different different date formats you have so you know exactly how many pieces to apply the fix in.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!